# Swift: UIPanGestureRecognizer bug swipe reverse

Tags: swift

I've created an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` but the problem is that when I slide the view to the right the view goes to the left.

When I slide the view to the left it goes to the right. Why?

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectPan(recognizer:)))
panGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = false
panGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false
separatorView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

and my function:

```
@objc func detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        self.startingConstant = self.centerConstraint.constant
    case .changed:
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        self.centerConstraint.constant = self.startingConstant + translation.x
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: You are swiping the screen, and you are using UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not near XCode to test this but I think you're doing the math backwards:

```
self.centerConstraint.constant = self.startingConstant + translation.x
```

Should be:

```
self.centerConstraint.constant = self.startingConstant - translation.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Zero.x,zero y are at the top left
You adding value to the center meaning.if center is (50,50) you adding to it and it will be(90,90) for example and thats will go to the right you need to subrtact translation.x not add